# vim — How can I search buffers?

Tags: search, vim, buffer

I am looking for some command like:

```
:b1!g/something_here/
```

where I supposedly search for a word "something_here" in the buffer "b1". How can I do it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I often do:

```
:rew
:bufdo 0
:bufdo g/something here/
:ls
```

The last :ls allows me to see all the buffers that are not positioned on line 1

Answer (score 6):

Well, go to buffer b1 and

```
:g/something here/
```

For searching through all open buffers there are various plugins, for which I think would be best if you took a peek on [www.vim.org](http://www.vim.org)

Edit: like this one - [buffergrep](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2255)
And my personal favorite for all kinds of searching: [compview](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1803)

Comment: The [grep.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=311) plugin is great - it seems to cover the functionality of both buffergrep and compview.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something simple:
:b0 |?somethingToSearch